# cannot write to seaweedfs

Tags: node.js, weed-fs

I am writing an image file to seaweedfs but it is throwing an err

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

below is the code

```
var seaweedfs = new weedClient({
            server: "localhost",
            port: 8080
        });

seaweedfs.write('C:/images/image.png').then(function(fileInfo) {
                        //return seaweedfs.read(fileInfo.fid);
                        console.log(fileInfo.fileUrl);
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        //error handling
                        console.log(err);
                    });
```

What I am doing wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. I was giving the wrong port number while initializing weedClient. When I run the weed server it shows port 9333 on the console. Just replaced 9333 instead of 8080 and it worked.

```
var seaweedfs = new weedClient({
            server: "localhost",
            port: 9333
        });
```

Comment: Are you still working on SeaweedFS? How was your experience.?